# Arrange python dictionary in specific order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary in following format:

```
data = [{'diff': '2:0', 'running': '-428:0', 'worked_hours': '12:0', 'name': '2015-05-21', 'dh': '10:0'},
{'diff': '-9:49', 'running': '-437:49', 'worked_hours': '0:11', 'name': '2015-05-22', 'dh': '10:0'},
{'diff': '0:0', 'running': '-437:49', 'worked_hours': '0:0', 'name': '2015-05-23', 'dh': '0:0'},
{'diff': '0:0', 'running': '-437:49', 'worked_hours': '0:0', 'name': '2015-05-24', 'dh': '0:0'}]
```

Now, I want to arrange my dictionary in the following way:

```
[{'name': '2015-05-21', 'dh': '10:0', 'worked_hours': '12:0', 'diff': '2:0', 'running': '-428:0'}
...]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Dictionary keys are not ordered. Perhaps you want an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: As Amber said, if you are using python 2.7+, take a look at OrderedDict